# Como Evitar Un Error

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo una lista con 2 elementos `a=[1,2]` si pongo por ejemplo a[2] pues marcara

```
> > Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<pyshell#13>", line 1, in <module>
>     if a[2]== IndexError(): IndexError: list index out of range
```

Si coloco un `if` para 'solucionarlo' que diga por ejemplo:

```
 if a[2]== IndexError: 
       print('Fuera de Rango')
```

Lógico No va a servir.

Se que ahi varias formas de resolver este problema como por ejemplo:

```
if a[2]==len(a):
    print('Fuera de Rango')
```

Pero la duda principal es si se puede evitar el error directamente como en el primer ejemplo sin necesidad de poner una condición como la longitud o algo así, sino usando una función que evite estos errores.

Gracias! y espero haberme hecho entender.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si quieres evitar que el programa termine con una excepción a causa de intentar un indexado con un índice fuera de rango ninguna de las opciones que muestras va a funcionar, en el momento que se intenta evaluar `a[2]` tendrás el `IndexError`.

Con un condicional que compruebe la longitud de la lista y compruebe si el índice es válido se debería hacer algo así:

```
a = [1, 2]

indice = 2

if not -len(a) <= indice < len(a):
    print('Fuera de Rango')
else:
    print(a[indice])
```

No obstante puedes usar un bloque `try-except` para capturar la excepción y manejarla según creas conveniente:

```
a = [1, 2]

indice = 2

try:
    print(a[indice])

except IndexError:
    print("Fuera de rango")
```

Básicamente el intérprete intenta llevar a cabo lo que hay dentro del  `try`, en caso de fallar a causa de un `IndexError` lleva a cabo lo que hay dentro del `except`. Puedes capturar cualquier excepción si `except` no va seguido de ningun error de forma explícita, aunque como cabe imaginar puede ser una gran causa de errores que pasan silenciados:

```
try:
    print(lista[indice])

except:
    print("Algún error ocurrió")
```

Puedes manejar distintos errores de forma diferenciada usando varias sentencias `except`:

```
try:
    print(lista[indice])

except IndexError:
    print("Índice fuera de rango")

except TypeError:
    print("Los indices de una lista han de ser enteros")
```

O capturar varios tipos en un mismo bloque usando una tupla:

```
try:
    print(lista[indice])

except (IndexError, TypeError):
    print("Índice no válido")
```

---

Puedes usar una función que te retorne el elemento de la lista si existe, o un valor que tu quieras en caso contrario, sin lanzar una excepción usando la misma idea (algo parecido a lo que hace el método `dict.get` por ejemplo).

```
a = [1, 2]


def get_list_element(lista, indice, default=None):
    try:
        return lista[indice]
    except IndexError:
        return default


elemento = get_list_element(a, 2)
print(elemento)  # None
elemento = get_list_element(a, 1)
print(elemento)  # 2
elemento = get_list_element(a, 2, default=0)
print(elemento)  # 0
```

Existen más opciones más "rebuscadas" creando nuestro propia clase contenedor o heredando (no recomendado por motivos que no viene al caso) / componiendo a partir de `list`. No obstante, si se requiere un contenedor que implemente la funcionalidad de `list` pero personalizado una buena opción es heredar de `collections.UserList`:

```
import collections



class MyList(collections.UserList):
    def  __getitem__(self, item, *args):
        try:
            return self.data.__getitem__(item)
        except IndexError:
            return None



a = MyList((1, 2))
print(a[1])  # 2
print(a[2])  # None
a.append(4)
print(a[2])  # 4
```

La clase `MyList` implementa todas las funcionalidades de un lista pero si indexamos con un índice incorrecto nos retorna `None`, no lanza una excepción.

Comment: Justo lo que buscaba, Gracias.

Answer (score 3):

Los errores que se producen en tiempo de ejecución (es decir, cuando se está ejecutando una instrucción concreta), desencadenan lo que se llama una *excepción*.

Las excepciones pueden capturarse desde el propio código y tomar una decisión en él con respecto a qué hacer. Sólo cuando no se capturan acaban por salir a la vista del usuario mostrando un *Traceback* como el que has puesto en tu pregunta. En ese *Traceback* se informa de qué excepción se produjo, y en qué línea de código, así como qué funciones estaban en ejecución en ese momento (es decir, desde qué función se había llamado a la que causó la excepción, y desde cuál se había llamado a su vez a la anterior, etc.)

En la documentación tienes [todos los detalles sobre cómo manejar las excepciones](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html), o cómo lanzar las tuyas propias.

Un breve resúmen sería el siguente.

**Manejar excepciones**

Cuando vas a ejecutar un bloque de código que podría fallar con una excepción, pon ese bloque de código dentro de una cláusula `try:`. A continuación de esa cláusula pon otra llamada `except X:`, siendo `X` el nombre de una excepción. Dentro de este segundo bloque, escribes código que será ejecutado en caso de que se produzca la excepción `X`. El bloque `except X` puedes repetirlo varias veces con distintos casos de `X`, para manejar de forma diferente cada excepción.

Así:

```
try:
    dato = a[2]
except IndexError:
    print("Fuera de rango")
    dato = 0
```

Fíjate que cuando se produce una excepción, además de (o en vez de ) imprimir qué error ha ocurrido, debes tomar alguna acción correctora. En el ejemplo anterior he supuesto que queríamos acceder a un dato, y que si salimos de rango el dato lo hago igual a cero. Esto puede tener sentido en tu aplicación o no tenerlo. Depende de qué vayas a hacer luego con ese dato. Otra opción podría ser hacer el `dato` igual a `None`. Otra opción más podría ser abortar la ejecución del programa con `quit()` para evitar que siga ejecutando nada más (que viene a ser lo que hace python cuando encuentra una excepción no manejada por código).

**Lanzar tu propia excepción**

También puedes estar escribiendo una función que va a ser llamada desde otro sitio, y quieres detectar posibles errores e informar a quien te llamó de que ha ocurrido uno de esos errores. Cuando quieres hacer eso, puedes poner `raise X()`, siendo `X` el nombre de la excepción que quieres elevar. Puede ser una de las que python tiene ya definidas, u otras que hayas creado (serían clases que hereden directa o indirectamente de la clase `Exception`).

Por ejemplo tu código podría contener algo como:

```
def obtener_elemento(a, n):
    if len(a) < n:
        raise IndexError("n debe ser menor que {}".format(len(a)))
    else:
        return a[n]
```

Quien llame a esa función pasando un `n` incorrecto se encontraría con la excepción `IndexError` que ha sido lanzada desde tu código al entrar por el `if`. Si no ha manejado esa excepción usando `try/catch`, la excepción subirá a la siguiente función que hubiera llamado a la que llamó a la tuya. Si al final se llega al programa principal sin que nadie haya tratado la excepción, el programa romperá y se le mostrará al usuario el mensaje que hemos puesto al lanzar la excepción.

Más detalles en [la documentación](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html) antes mencionada.

Comment: Gracias amigo, muy útil lo de la función Raise.